# How to plot a graph in Mathematica?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

```
DSolve[{Derivative[2][Subscript[u, 00]][y] + 
     Rey*S*Derivative[1][Subscript[u, 00]][y] == -Rey*
     Gr*((E^(Pr Rey S - Pr Rey S y) (-1 + E^(Pr Rey S y)))/(-1 + E^(
       Pr Re S))), 
   Subscript[u, 00][0] == h*Derivative[1][Subscript[u, 00]][0], 
   Subscript[u, 00][1] == 1}, Subscript[u, 00][y], y] // FullSimplify
```

Output is :

```
{{Subscript[u, 0][
    y] -> (E^(-Rey S (Pr (-1 + y) + y)) (-E^(Rey S y) Gr - 
        E^(S (Rey + Pr (Re + Rey (-1 + y)))) (-1 + Pr) Pr Rey S^2 + 
        E^(Rey S (1 + y)) Gr (1 + h Rey S) + 
        E^(S (Pr Re + Rey + Pr Rey (-1 + y) + Rey y)) (-1 + 
           Pr) Pr Rey S^2 (1 + h Rey S) - 
        E^(Rey S (1 + Pr y)) Gr (1 + Pr (-1 + Pr + h Pr) Rey S) + 
        E^(Rey S (1 + Pr (-1 + y))) (Gr + (-1 + Pr) Pr Rey S^2) - 
        E^(Rey S (1 + Pr (-1 + y) + y)) (1 + 
           h Rey S) (Gr + (-1 + Pr) Pr Rey S^2) - 
        E^(Rey S (1 + y + Pr y))
          Gr (-1 + Pr) Pr Rey S (1 + h Rey S) (-1 + y) + 
        E^((1 + Pr) Rey S y)
          Gr (1 + Pr Rey S (h Pr + (-1 + Pr) y))))/((-1 + E^(
        Pr Re S)) (-1 + Pr) Pr Rey S^2 (-1 + 
        E^(Rey S) (1 + h Rey S)))}}
```

From the output, When I try to plot the function u_00, the plot was empty in Mathematica.

How can I solve this out?

Comment: Please copy the code into your question so people don't have to retype it to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In[1]:= Rey = 2; S = 3; Gr = 4; Pr = 5; ReNoNoNo = 6; (*NOT Re *) h = 7;
sol = Subscript[u, 0][y] /. DSolve[{Derivative[2][Subscript[u, 00]][y] + 
   Rey*S*Derivative[1][Subscript[u, 00]][y] == -Rey*Gr*((E^(Pr Rey S -
   Pr Rey S y) (-1 + E^(Pr Rey S y)))/(-1 + E^(Pr ReNoNoNo S))), 
   Subscript[u, 00][0] == h*Derivative[1][Subscript[u, 00]][0], 
   Subscript[u, 00][1] == 1}, Subscript[u, 00][y], y][[1, 1]];
Plot[sol, {y, 0, 1}]

Out[2]= ...PlotSnipped...
```